# Ionic Reload Blank Page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When serving my Ionic application, every even refresh is a blank page.

E.g. the first time I load my app it works, and after making a code change the live reload displays a blank page, then it works, then a blank page and so on.

How do I find the cause of this? I've compared its routing setup to that of a project which works (a blank project) and they seem to work the same.

When it fails to live reload and shows a blank page, no errors are displaying in the Chrome DevTools console, or in my terminal.

This occurs when serving the app using any of the commands:

```sh
ionic serve
ionic cordova run android -l
ionic serve --devapp
```

My app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post app.component.ts

Comment: Replacing app.component.ts with the default generated one still produces this same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a routing issue. My empty path redirected to my dashboard, which had an `AuthGuard` associated with it. The `AuthGuard` would reject my navigation, leaving me with a blank page.

As for why every even reload, I think my logic for logging in was flipping some boolean `isAuthenticated` flag each time my auto sign-in code ran.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit ctrl+f5 to bust cache

I have same issue specially when I switch v3 to v4 or vise-versa

Answer (score 0):

it is your cashing issue and what data are you loading in your

`app.component.ts`

its due to loading heavy task in your `component.ts`